# mysql order with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

i came across this problem. I am developing using rails with activerecord. I have 2 tables `Cities(id, title, place_count)` and `Places(id, title, city_id, position)`

and i am joining them like this:

```
Place.joins(:city).order("cities.place_count DESC")
```

in view i render this records grouped like there will be places ordered by there count in cities and when city changes it changes title of the city. something like this.

```
<% @places.each do | place| %>
<% city_id = place.city.id %>
        <% unless city_title == place.city.title %>
          <% city_title = place.city.title %>
          <tr class="caption all_places city-<%= city_id %>"><td colspan="3"><%= city_title %></td></tr>
        <% end %>
        <tr id="place-<%= place.id %>" class="hoverable all_places city-<%= city_id %>">
          <td><%= place.title %></td>
          <td>
            <p>
              <%= place.address %><br><%= place.phone_number %><br/><%= link_to place.site, "http://#{place.site}", target:"_blank", rel: "nofollow", class: "place-link" if place.site.present? %>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td><%= image_tag place.small_logo, alt: place.title %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
```

In `Places` table there are another column called position which is in city scope, so every city have that place position. What i want that when i select it selects firstly ordered by count and in that scope ordered by position and if position null than nulls last. So it woul look something like this:

```
city with count 10
  place 0
  place 1
  place 2
  place 3
  null
  null
city with count 5
  place 0
  place 1
... so on
```

**EDIT:**

I tried something like this:

```
Place.joins(:city).order("cities.places_count DESC").order("-position DESC")
```

if the places count under city is different that it works just fine, but when 2 or more cities have  the same places count, than they are mixed together!

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found answer my self. I played around a bit and it seems to work just fine. What i did is ordered by city_tite, before ordering by position

```
Place.joins(:city).order("cities.places_count DESC").order(""cities.title ASC).order("-position DESC")
```